# Нет отступов между айтемами на некоторых устройствах

Tags: java, android, gui, recyclerview

В чем может быть проблема, на разных устройствах приложение отображается по разному, и шрифт в `TextView` выставлен `android:typeface="serif"`, но работает только на `android 4.4`

**Android 4.4**

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Android 5.0.1**

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Android 5.0.0**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

они все 1080*1920 - 480dpi, 1-случай это Galaxy S4 (Android 4.4.4) - API 19 - это виртуальное устройство, 2-й Galaxy S4 (Android 5.0.1) - API 21 это реальное устройство, 3-й Nexus 5 (Android 5.0.0) - API 21 - это виртуальное устройство.
В ресурсах папки с квалификатором *-v21* нет.

Активити наследуется от `AppCompatActivity`, а фрагмент от `Fragment`.

Если я правильно понимаю, то проблема в самом `RecyclerView`, т.к. нужно добавить один общий `addItemDecoration()`, но как это сделать?

вот код добавления `RecyclerView` в `adapter`:

```
rvCategories = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv);

    adapter = new CategoryAdapter(getContext(), addCategories(TYPE), TYPE, null);
    GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    rvCategories.setAdapter(adapter);
    rvCategories.setLayoutManager(glm);
    rvCategories.setLayoutManager(glm);
    rvCategories.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rvCategories.addItemDecoration(**вот тут что?**);
```

Comment: А шрифты на сколько я помню через typeface можно выставлять только с 4.4, поэтому на младших версиях они выглядят по другому

Comment: @pavel163, так ведь я проверяю выше чем 4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Ответ на проблему с отступами в `RecyclerView` нашел [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30794046/5564588)

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, NUM_COLUMNS);
ItemOffsetDecoration itemDecoration = new ItemOffsetDecoration(context, R.dimen.item_offset);
mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
```

2) Проблему со шрифтом [тут](https://gist.github.com/artem-zinnatullin/7749076)

Также надо прописать класс `MyApp` в `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
     android:label="@string/app_name" 
     android:name=".MyApp">

     ...
</application>
```